# In Airflow GUI - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.cncf

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

**Apache Airflow version**

2.5.2
**What happened**

Not able to create new (Admin - > Connection -> When I press + sign it gives below error regarding airflow.providers.cncf

**Error:**

Ooops!

Something bad has happened.

Airflow is used by many users, and it is very likely that others had similar problems and you can easily find
a solution to your problem.

Consider following these steps:

```
gather the relevant information (detailed logs with errors, reproduction steps, details of your deployment)

find similar issues using:
    GitHub Discussions
    GitHub Issues
    Stack Overflow
    the usual search engine you use on a daily basis

if you run Airflow on a Managed Service, consider opening an issue using the service support channels

if you tried and have difficulty with diagnosing and fixing the problem yourself, consider creating a bug report.
Make sure however, to include all relevant details and results of your investigation so far.
```

Python version: 3.9.5
Airflow version: 2.5.0

```
   

Traceback (most recent call last): File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
    > 2528, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1825, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1823, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
1799, in dispatch_request return
self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/decorators.py",
line 125, in wrapper return f(*args, **kwargs) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py",
line 133, in wraps return f(self, *args, **kwargs) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/views.py",
line 594, in add return self.render_template( File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py",
line 322, in render_template return render_template( File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py",
line 147, in render_template return _render(app, template, context)
File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py",
line 130, in _render rv = template.render(context) File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py",
line 1301, in render self.environment.handle_exception() File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py",
line 936, in handle_exception raise
rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/conn_create.html",
line 20, in top-level template code {% extends
'appbuilder/general/model/add.html' %} File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/add.html",
line 2, in top-level template code {% import
'appbuilder/general/lib.html' as lib %} File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/base.html",
line 1, in top-level template code {% extends base_template %} File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/main.html",
line 21, in top-level template code {% from 'airflow/_messages.html'
import show_message %} File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/baselayout.html",
line 2, in top-level template code {% import 'appbuilder/baselib.html'
as baselib %} File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/init.html",
line 50, in top-level template code {% block tail %} File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/conn_create.html",
line 31, in block 'tail' <script id="field_behaviours"
type="text/json">{{ widgets["add"].field_behaviours }}</script> File
"/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py",
line 485, in getattr return getattr(obj, attribute) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/functools.py", line 969, in get val =
self.func(instance) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line
4217, in field_behaviours return
json.dumps(ProvidersManager().field_behaviours) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py",
line 957, in field_behaviours self.initialize_providers_hooks() File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py",
line 327, in wrapped_function func(*args, **kwargs) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py",
line 413, in initialize_providers_hooks
self.initialize_providers_list() File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py",
line 327, in wrapped_function func(*args, **kwargs) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py",
line 390, in initialize_providers_list
self._discover_all_providers_from_packages() File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py",
line 462, in _discover_all_providers_from_packages provider_info =
entry_point.load()() File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/init.py",
line 207, in load module = import_module(match.group('module')) File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in
import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
level) File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import File "", line 1007, in
_find_and_load File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File "", line 1030, in
_gcd_import File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 228, in
_call_with_frames_removed File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load File "", line 984, in
_find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.cncf'
```

**What you think should happen instead**

This happens when a new connection is being created freshly through Airflow Web - Admin - Connections - and then by pressing the Plus + symbol for creating a **new connection for the system**
**How to reproduce**

This can be reproduced if we are going for creating the new connection. Its not even giving the chance to edit the existing connection.
**Operating System**: GNU Linux 3.10.0-1160.81.1.el7.x86_64
**Versions of Apache Airflow Providers**: Airflow 2.5.0
Deployment
**Installed on**: AWS Ec2

Comment: $python3.9 -m pip list | grep cncf.kubernetes
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes 5.2.2